# HTML or Script Interpretaion in React and normal HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser

I am new to `React` and I am having this doubt. I want to render list of `li` elements to the `ul`. I am doing the looping and rendering to the UI. **Everything is working cool as expected**.

But my doubt is while rendering the elements, if the element is `<b>sampletext</b>` it's rendering as it is. I am wondering why the elements are not interpreted by browser and not showing as bold text like **sampletext**.

I have tried to add dynamic elements in normal html and js with the same text `<b>sampletext</b>` but it's interpreted as **sampletext** and displaying as bold text.

Can anyone help me with the how React handles the text elements while rendering without interpreting the tags in the elements ? Thanks in Advance.

EDIT ::

```
render: function() {
    var arr = ['sampletext1', 'sampletext2', '<b>sampletext3</b>'];
    var arrElements = arr.map(function(elem){
                    return <li>{elem}</li>;
                  })

    return  <ul>{ arrElements }</ul>
}
```

**Note** : I have got the reference of the code from one tutorial website and learning myself about looping the elements

Comment: Can you show the code that you already wrote?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your desired output, and how does it differ from the actual output?

Comment: Actually i tried to print the elements in the array i specified as "arr" but i got the third element <b>sampletext3</b> I thought it would be bold after rendering. but in react is not happening @jered

Comment: What does your rendered html look like if you hit F12?

Comment: In React : <li><b>sampletext3</b></li> @ Phil Bellamy

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want the third array element to be a JSX element rather than a string:

```
 var arr = ['sampletext1', 'sampletext2', <b>sampletext3</b>];
```

Edit:

To illustrate why this situation arises, please see example functions of how JSX is compiled down to JavaScript below and the differences in each case.

JSX:

```
function bAsJsxElement() {
  return <li><b>sampletext3</b></li>;
}

function bAsString() {
  return <li>{'<b>sampletext3</b>'}</li>;
}
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
function bAsJsxElement() {
  return React.createElement(
    'li',
    null,
    React.createElement(
      'b',
      null,
      'sampletext3'
    )
  );
}

function bAsString() {
  return React.createElement(
    'li',
    null,
    '<b>sampletext3</b>'
  );
}
```

If the third parameter passed into `React.CreateElement` is a string, it will be put between quotes when rendered to the HTML.

Comment: actually my doubt is how the browser doesn't render the HTML in react

Comment: Maybe read a bit more about JSX here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html. If you want your <b> rendered as HTML as opposed to a string then you need to make it a JSX element. If you pass it in as a string then it will be treated as such when JSX converts to React.CreateComponent

Comment: Thank you @Phil Bellamy your answer is more clear and how JSX is handled by React